# How to copy one tailer's read index to apply into another tailer using Chronicle Queue

Tags: message-queue, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I create a tailerA and use tailerA read to the 100th message.
And I create another tailerB

```java
ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.single("/home/data").rollCycle(rollCycles).build()

ExcerptTailer tailerA = queue.createTailer("A")
ExcerptTailer tailerB = queue.createTailer("B")

for(int i = 1;i < 101;i++){
   tailerA.read()  <- this is a simplified code for read
}
```

Use tailerB to read,it supposed to read from 1th to 100th one by one ,But what I need is to use tailerB reading start from 100th message. How can I use tailerA to copy the 100th information into tailerB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the index an `ExcerptTailer` points to with

```
long index = tailerA.index();
```

and you can set the tailer to be this index with

```
boolean success = tailerB.moveToIndex(index);
```

Assuming this is successful both tailers will read the same Excerpt next.

Comment: It solved my problem completely,but by the way ,I noticed that if tailerA has read to the end ,then tailerB.moveToIndex(index) will return false,I'm curious about why it designed to return false.

Comment: @Asuka_Truth it returns false as there is no entry at that index, yet.